# Display name of selected file from p:fileUpload in a p:inputText

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, filenames

I have a `<p:fileUpload>` and a `<p:inputText>`.

When the enduser selects a file with `<p:fileUpload>`, I would like to immediately show its file name in the `<p:inputText>`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: if you want someone to develop code for you, please go to https://www.freelancer.com/hire/Java/. If you have code that does not work, please post it here (in [mcve] style)

Comment: Answer depends on whether you use p:fileUpload in simple or advanced mode.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{controller.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced"  
     update="formName:fileName" auto="true"  />
   <p:inputText id="fileName" value="#{controller.uploadedFileName}" />
```

And in controller in handleFileUpload method you can get the file name as

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
       uploadedFileName=event.getFile().getFileName();
    }
```